# HTML/CSS Left sliding menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am building a site where I want a menu to slide from the left of the screen (`width:0px`), to the right (`width:250px`) animated with jQuery.

What I did is create a container `div`, and inside two divs `#menuLeft` and `#content`.

My question is then, how do I make `#content's` width equal to whatever's left of the screen in css, knowing that my container is 100% width, and `#menuLeft` is variable.

Thank you very much!

The HTML:

```
<div id="all">
    <div id="leftMenu">
    </div>

    <div id="content">
    </div>

</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#all{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background:#445566;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-top:40px;
    width:100%;
    height:2000px;

}

#leftMenu{
    float:left;
    background:#888888;
    height:1000px;
    width:250px;
}
#content{

    float:right;
    height:1000px;
    background:#55ffaa;
    width:1000px;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle of your code snippets to allow us to visualise what you want to achieve?

Comment: http://inspartnership.org.uk/ <- make your browser mobile width (make it thinner until the menu on the left disappears) then click 'open menu' at the top - is this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I added the code, ;)
@GrahamRitchie the website you showed uses the layout i want to achieve, only I want the content on the right to be able to rescale to whatever width is left after the menu appears

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z8mAY/21/ <- see that fiddle for starters - however I WOULD NOT recommend that behaviour unless you are building a fixed-width site (in which case - DONT :-P)

Comment: Thank you very much!, but I had another idea, i'll just put the menu over the `#all` div and it should work on screens bigger than 800 px ^^

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to achieve something like: [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ZALuA/)?

Here's the code:

```
<div id="all">
    <div id="leftMenu"></div>
    <div id="content">some text</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#all{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background:#445566;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-top:40px;
    width:100%;
    height:2000px;
}
#leftMenu{
    float:left;
    background:#888888;
    height:1000px;
    width:250px;
}
#content{
    height:1000px;
    background:#55ffaa;
}
```

Try resizing the results panel or the browser.